# MAT_DATE_FORMATS definition/meaning of fields

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-material2

Material example for [customizing-the-parse-and-display-formats](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#customizing-the-parse-and-display-formats) for date picker uses custom MAT_DATE_FORMATS

```
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};
```

I could not find where and how these fields like `dateA11yLabel` will come into play. What I could figure out was `display.dateInput` is used in displaying selected date on calendar and `display.monthYearLabel` is used in the select drop-down of year selector.

1. Where are rest of the fields used?
2. When writing custom MAT_DATE_FORMATS is it mandatory to define all
   fields?

Comment: This is a pretty good link : https://www.concretepage.com/angular-material/angular-material-datepicker-format

Answer (score 36):

Well, I figured out the following:

[image: datepicker]

```
 parse: {

    dateInput: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
  }, 
  display: {

    dateInput: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM-YYYY',
  },
```

- with `parse.dateInput`: you can let the user enter any type of date with any format, and the date adapter will reformat it to the format you specify in this attribute
- with `display.dateInput` you can specify the input date format (marked with 1)
- `display.monthYearLabel` you can specify the area marked with 2

unfortunately, I still don't know about the rest!

Comment: I wrote about the a11y ones here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68810517/11991371

Comment: You explain it better than the official angular material documentation

Answer (score 5):

A11Y - means accessibility. Look here https://material.angular.io/cdk/a11y/overview
and here https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#accessibility

According that I think these formats are used to display datepicker when accessibility mode on.